# How to Get Selected Item From LibGDX List?

Tags: libgdx

I’ve tried a few different methods to get a selected item from a list (see code below), but everything I’ve tried only returns the first item in the list no matter which item was actually selected. Visually it appears to work because the correct item gets highlighted when it is clicked on.

As a general overview of what I’m trying to do, I have a folder that contains all of the saved preset files (json files), then I read the names of all the files into a list of strings, from this list a specific preset can be selected, and then I have a separate “load” textbutton that loads the item that was selected from the list. But as mentioned above, the correct item is not loaded from the list when the load button is clicked.

Here is my code:

```
public class PresetLoadMenu extends Menu {
    private GUI gui;
    private SaveManager saveManager;

    private Table scrollPaneContainerTable;
    private ScrollPane scrollPane;
    private Table scrollTable;
    private List<String> presetList;
    private TextButton loadButton;

    private FileHandle rootFolderHandle = Gdx.files.external(“presets/”);   

    public PresetLoadMenu(GUI gui){
        this.gui = gui;
        refreshList();

        scrollTable = new Table();
        scrollTable.add(presetList);        
        scrollPane = new ScrollPane(scrollTable);

        scrollPaneContainerTable = new Table();
        scrollPaneContainerTable.add(scrollPane).size(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight()*.2f);
        add(scrollPaneContainerTable);

        row();

        loadButton = new TextButton("LOAD", gui.menuStyles.getMenuOkCancelButtonStyle());
        loadButton.addCaptureListener(new ChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor){
                // METHOD 1:
                // System.out.println("SELECTED PRESET: " + presetList.getSelected());

                // METHOD 2:
                // System.out.println("SELECTED PRESET: " + presetList.getSelection().getLastSelected());

                // METHOD 3:
                // for (int i=0; i<presetList.getSelection().size(); i++){
                //     System.out.println("INDEX: " + i + "  SELECTED PRESET: " + presetList.getSelection().toArray().get(i));
                // }
            }
        });
        add(loadButton).size(loadButton.getWidth(), loadButton.getHeight());        
    }

    public void refreshList(){
        FileHandle[] files = rootFolderHandle.list();
        Array<String> namesArray = new Array<String>();
        for(FileHandle file: files) {
            namesArray.add(file.name());
        }

        presetList = new List<String>(gui.menuStyles.getListStyle());
        presetList.setItems(namesArray);        
    }
}
```

The last method I tried using a for loop just to see if it would print out the other items that I clicked on, but it still printed the first item just one time and didn't detect that I had clicked on any of the other items.

Comment: And what's wrong with using `presetList.getSelected()` ?

Comment: The problem was actually something else outside of the class that I posted, so presetList.getSelected() may work just fine now that I figured out what the problem was. But before I figured it out, I had swapped out the List for a ButtonGroup, which is actually better for me than using the List anyways so it worked out. The List has a built in listener that selects the item on touch down, so items would get selected when trying to scroll up or down. With a button I can have a listener just for the checked state, which is what I want. Thanks.

Comment: So please answer your question to close it :-)

Comment: @Sebastian, done. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On request I'm copying my last comment as an answer in order to close my question.

The problem was actually something else outside of the class that I posted, so presetList.getSelected() may work just fine now that I figured out what the problem was. But before I figured it out, I had swapped out the List for a ButtonGroup, which is actually better for me than using the List anyways so it worked out. The List has a built in listener that selects the item on touch down, so items would get selected when trying to scroll up or down. With a button I can have a listener just for the checked state, which is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your answer, I solved it by creating a table of TextButton (buttonTable) , every of them initialize with an string:

```
final TextButton button = new TextButton("my string",skin);
```

and a listener:

```
button.addListener(new ClickListener() {
    public void clicked (InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
        button.getText()));
    }
});
```

This buttonTable initialize a ScrollPane to allow vertical scrolling:

```
scrollPane = new ScrollPane(buttonsTable);
```

This scrollPane was added to table used to format my form:

```
mainTable.add(scrollPane);
```

This table was the actor added to the stage:

```
stage.addActor(mainTable);
```